# Where can I find the error messages for IntelliJ Maven repository errors?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am having trouble updating my maven repositories in IntelliJ. I have three repositories that show errors, but IntelliJ doesn't show the full error messages.

I am looking in File >> Settings >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Build Tools >> Maven >> Repositories
This is what I see:

[image: Error Screenshot]

I have tried the update button in the upper right, but I always get the "Error" message. What I can't figure out is where I can view what the actual errors are. Can anyone tell me where these error messages are logged or displayed?

I can build from the command line just fine. I am using the following:

- Windows 10 Pro
- IntelliJ Ultimate 2002.3.2
- Maven 3.6.3
- Java jdk1.8.0_66

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085).

Comment: First check to build on plain command line ... then tell use about which IDEA versions, JDK, Maven version you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information shows up in the idea log. This log can be found in the Help menu in the top search bar of the IntelliJ window.

Help >> Show log in explorer

You can then open and search the log using your preferred text editor.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085

@CrazyCoder provided this information in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stand-alone maven instance, and builds work fine from the command line, but they do not work from IntelliJ, it's likely that IJ is not configured to use the same maven settings as your system.

IntelliJ will use its bundled maven runtime rather than the one from your system. IJ will also use default maven settings locations.

You can modify these under the Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven screen. Make sure the settings match those in your systems MAVEN_HOME .